# Porting OpenGL app to Metal API

Tags: opengl, metal

In OpenGL I got this ( shortened code )

```
void Mesh::CreateBuffer() { 
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Buffers[POS_VB] );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Positions[0] /*vec3*/) * iVerticeNum, &Positions[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( POSITION_LOCATION );
    glVertexAttribPointer( POSITION_LOCATION, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0 );

    // Fill index buffer.
    glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Buffers[INDEX_BUFFER] );
    glBufferData( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Indices[0] /*unsigned int*/) * iIndiceNum, &Indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW );

}

void Mesh::Render() {

    // bind vertex arrays here!
    .....

    glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, this->NumIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    ....
}
```

The code above is working perfectly in my engine. But when I've decided to port it to Metal API I got some problems, - it just renders half of model using **index data**, there are **NO** groups in its mesh, it's just simple mesh. But when I try to render it using vertice data ( drawPrimitives ) it renders fine.

Here's Metal code I am using to initialize and render my mesh:

```
    INIT
    ....
    // Initialize mesh.
    MetalMesh mesh;

    mesh.vertexBuffer = [MetalDataBase->device newBufferWithBytes:Positions/* Vertice data */
                                            length:sizeof(vec3) * iNumVertices
                                           options:MTLResourceOptionCPUCacheModeDefault];
    mesh.indexBuffer = [MetalDataBase->device newBufferWithBytes:Indices
                                           length:sizeof(unsigned int) * iNumIndices
                                          options:MTLResourceOptionCPUCacheModeDefault];

    DRAW
    // Drawing..
    [MetalDataBase->commandEncoder setVertexBuffer:metalResource->metalMeshes[index].vertexBuffer offset:0 atIndex:0];

    // DrawPrimitives renders mesh **fine**, as it should.
    //[MetalDataBase->commandEncoder drawPrimitives:MTLPrimitiveTypeTriangle vertexStart:0 vertexCount:iVerticeNum]; 

    // But it doesn't, it just renders half of model,
    // while **iIndiceNum** is right number with its data.
    [MetalDataBase->commandEncoder drawIndexedPrimitives:MTLPrimitiveTypeTriangle indexCount:iIndiceNum indexType:MTLIndexTypeUInt32 indexBuffer:metalResource->metalMeshes[index].indexBuffer indexBufferOffset:0];
```

Comment: The singular forms of the words "indices" and "vertices" are "index" and"vertex", respectively. The confusion that arises is presumably why John Carmack doesn't use the Latin form of the plurals, and instead uses "indexes" and "vertexes".

Comment: While I don't know Metal, I noticed that you use `iNumIndices` in one place, and `iIndiceNum` later in the code. Are those the same values?

Comment: These are the same values ( iIndiceNum is just passed through parameters ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I've managed what's wrong. 
Similar thread can be found here: 
http://www.gamedev.net/topic/544669-d3d9-only-1st-submesh-renders-w-indexed-vertexbuffer-solved/

Soo, firstly, I am using several sub meshes, in OpenGL I have something like this:

```
    // Count the number of vertices and indices
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < pScene->mNumMeshes; ++i ) {
        m_Entries[i].MaterialIndex = pScene->mMeshes[i]->mMaterialIndex;
        m_Entries[i].NumIndices    = (pScene->mMeshes[i]->mNumFaces * VerticesPerPrim);
        m_Entries[i].NumVertices   = pScene->mMeshes[i]->mNumVertices;
        m_Entries[i].BaseVertex    = NumVertices;
        m_Entries[i].BaseIndex     = NumIndices;

        Con::Printf( LOG_INFO, "\t\tMesh #%i: %i vertices and %i indices\r\n", i, NumVertices, NumIndices );

        NumVertices += pScene->mMeshes[i]->mNumVertices;
        NumIndices  += m_Entries[i].NumIndices;
    }

    .... load bones, textures etc..

    // Load INDEXIES(haha) data now
    if(something) { ..
        for( unsigned int i = 0; i < paiMesh->mNumFaces; ++i ) {
            const aiFace & Face = paiMesh->mFaces[i];

            //if( Face.mNumIndices == 3 ) {
                Indices[iIndiceNum] = Face.mIndices[0]; ++iIndiceNum;
                Indices[iIndiceNum] = Face.mIndices[1]; ++iIndiceNum;
                Indices[iIndiceNum] = Face.mIndices[2]; ++iIndiceNum;
            //}
        }
     }
```

But after some raging and hair pulling I found a link I posted before, it helped me ( look into the last post ). So in Metal I have something like this now: ( notice the **'+NumVertices'** in the second line in 'for' loop )

```
    const unsigned int VerticesPerPrim = m_withAdjacencies ? 6 : 3;

    // Count the number of vertices and indices
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < pScene->mNumMeshes; ++i ) {
        m_Entries[i].MaterialIndex = pScene->mMeshes[i]->mMaterialIndex;
        m_Entries[i].NumIndices    = (pScene->mMeshes[i]->mNumFaces * VerticesPerPrim)  + NumVertices ;
        m_Entries[i].NumVertices   = pScene->mMeshes[i]->mNumVertices;
        m_Entries[i].BaseVertex    = NumVertices;
        m_Entries[i].BaseIndex     = NumIndices;

        g_Console->Print( LOG_INFO, "\t\tMesh #%i: %i vertices and %i indices\r\n", i, NumVertices, NumIndices );

        NumVertices += pScene->mMeshes[i]->mNumVertices;
        NumIndices  += m_Entries[i].NumIndices;
    }


    .. load bones, textures, etc now....

    // Load INDEXIEES data
    if( something ) {
      int offset = 0;

        if( MeshIndex > 0 )
            for ( int k = 0; k < MeshIndex; k++ )
                offset += wtf->mMeshes[k]->mNumVertices;

        for( unsigned int i = 0; i < paiMesh->mNumFaces; ++i ) {
            const aiFace & Face = paiMesh->mFaces[i];

            //if( Face.mNumIndices == 3 ) {
                Indices[iIndiceNum] = Face.mIndices[0] + offset; ++iIndiceNum;
                Indices[iIndiceNum] = Face.mIndices[1] + offset; ++iIndiceNum;
                Indices[iIndiceNum] = Face.mIndices[2] + offset; ++iIndiceNum;
            //}
        }
    }
```

Haha, thanks for 'indexes', 'vertexes' grammar tips.

Here's how I render it using Metal:

```
// index = mesh index in Metal API(kinda array)
for( int i = 0; i < mesh[j]->mNumMeshes; ++i ) 
[MetalDataBase->commandEncoder drawIndexedPrimitives:MTLPrimitiveTypeTriangle indexCount:m_Entries[i].numIndices indexType:MTLIndexTypeUInt32 indexBuffer:metalResource->metalMeshes[index].indexBuffer indexBufferOffset:0];
```

Soo, now I got fully loaded mesh ( and its sub meshes ):

[image: Yup, here it is]